# Flutter and Dart plugin not installed errror when downgrade flutter even though they are installed on android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-plugin

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
 [√] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.4.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.804], locale en-IE)
 [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
     X Android license status unknown.
       Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
       See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit 
 https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed
       instructions.
 [!] Android Studio
     X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
     X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
 [√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
 [!] Connected device
     ! No devices available
```

I was using the latest version of flutter, ran flutter doctor, everything was fine. I then downgraded flutter now it's saying I don't have the flutter and Dart pluggins installed even though I do.

[image]

I ran this command - `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and received the following error

`A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run: C:\Users\willm\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update`

I then ran the command it told me to run and received this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 5 more
```

I have now ran out of ideas, any advice on what to do without upgrading flutter again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some solutions that maybe helpful

### 1). Solution 1

Run  `Flutter clean` ann rebuild the app

### 2). Solution 2

Accept Licenses by running following commands
You just have to accept license by running this command

```
yes | sdkmanager --licenses
```

for Linux Use:

```
yes | ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

for Windows Use:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

Note: set

```
%ANDROID_HOME%
```

as

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

After that check licenses

Flutter:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

### 3).Solution 3

the current SDK version is incompatible with Java 9.

So, to solve it, you can downgrade your java version to Java 8, or with a workaround, you can export the following option on your terminal:

Linux:

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

Windows:

```
set JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

And to make it stick, you can export the JAVA_OPTS in your profile file on Linux (.zshrc, .bashrc and etc.) or add as an environment permanently on Windows.

Then, you can type the flutter or sdkmanager command:

Flutter:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

sdkmanager:

```
sdkmanager --licenses
```

and type Y when needed to accept the licenses.

Answer (score 0):

so i was experiencing the same issue after upgrading to flutter 2.0, but some packages aren't ready. because of that i had to downgrade. Even though flutter doctor said:

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.

I was still able to build and test app without issues. So try rebuilding and running app. hopefully when it's save to upgrade to 2.0 these little things will go.